# "Poynting vector" for transverse waves in elastic solid

Tags: elasticity

What is the expression or name for the vector that gives the direction and intensity associated with the energy flux or momentum flux carried by transverse waves in an elastic solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learned that this is called the *elastodynamic Pointing vector*,
$$ \mathbf{S} = -\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{T},$$
where $\mathbf v$ is the particle velocity and $\mathbf T$ is the stress tensor.

Source: [C. Dean, Braselton](https://books.google.nl/books?id=B_3ICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Theoretical and Computational Acoustics 2003, citing Auld, *Acoustic fields and waves in solids, vol. I* (1973).

For example, consider a purely transversal wave propagating along the $z$ axis, with the displacement along the $x$ axis. A volume element may have an instantaneous velocity $v$ in the $x$ direction. The stress tensor will describe $x$-$z$ shear stress. Then we would have
$$ \mathbf S = -(v, 0, 0) \cdot
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & \sigma_{xz} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \sigma_{zx} & 0 & 0 
 \end{array}\right) 
 =
 (0, ~0, -v\sigma_{zx}).
$$

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure this definition also covers transverse waves but I've checked the book and can't see any reason why not.

Comment: I added an example for a transversal wave.